# Why can't I see a separate curl file along with all the libcurl files after building it from source?

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, osx-snow-leopard, build

I downloaded the source file from https://curl.haxx.se/download/ (curl-7.59.0.tar.bz2) to build the curl command line tool, or so I thought. I followed the instructions on curl's site (`./configure, make, make install`) without difficulty.

The document (https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) says that the source should provide both curl and libcurl. **I can only see libcurl when I open the directory, which is what I don't understand.** Here is the output when I look inside the usr/local/lib directory, where libcurl was installed:

```
my-macbook:lib Kumitan$ ls
libcurl.4.dylib libcurl.a   libcurl.dylib   libcurl.la  pkgconfig
```

All of these are libcurl. I get the feeling that I must have missed out a step or I'm not understanding something here.

I understand that curl (the application) is made using libcurl (the library), so why am I not seeing a separate curl tool in this directory? **Why can I only see libcurl files if this is meant to install curl as well?** Surely the curl tool would also be built along with libcurl? Or are they the same thing?

Background information: My computer is running Mac OSX 10.6.8. I'm trying to update/upgrade the current version of curl on the computer (7.19) by installing a newer version so that I can use curl to install homebrew. I can't upgrade to Mountain Lion (OSX 10.7).

NB: I can't just install curl using homebrew, because my curl version is too old to actually run the script to install homebrew itself.

Comment: [build and install curl from source](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill I should have said I read that in the question. Edited.

Comment: I'd expect the default install directory for curl to be /usr/local/bin. Prior to make install curl would be found in src. (Your question isn't clear).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this.

To answer my own question, it turns out that `libcurl` and `curl` were kept in separate folders, which is why I couldn't see `curl` and `curl-config` in the same folder as all the `libcurl` stuff.

Libcurl went into `usr/local/lib` and could also be found in `usr/local/bin/lib` (for some reason), and curl (the files `curl` and `curl-config`) went into `usr/local/bin/bin`.

I will also show how I solved my issue.

The computer's current curl installation was in `/usr/bin`, which is also probably where it expects to find curl. For this reason, it didn't take note of the new curl in `usr/local`. So I deleted the curl and curl-config files that were currently in `/usr/bin`, then moved the new curl files from `/usr/local/...` into `/usr/bin` to replace the old ones.

Please note: Deleting your system-provided files in dangerous. You should leave them there so that things that need to can still access the old version. See comments for more.

Now `curl -V` is returning `7.59.0`, which means it's been updated. Yay!

Comment: Congrats on solving your problem, but you should **never** delete files provided by the Operating System. The default curl may be used by system tools that rely on features specific to the version installed. In the future, add /usr/local/bin to the front of your PATH, so the new version will be found by anything _you_ do, while the older version can still be accessed by system tools.

Comment: @MMB Thanks for the advice. I will add it into my answer so that other's don't make the same mistake.